# onFocusChanged Listener not triggered on a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, focus, android-relativelayout

I have a number of buttons.

I wrapped "button2" in a relative layout
Then I setOnFocusChangedListener for all other buttons and the new wrapper RelativeLayout.

Note that the RelativeLayout is a sibling to all other buttons.

**The problem is:
onFocusChangedListener is not triggered on the RelativeLayout**,
but it works fine on all other siblings.

Why is that? Am I missing something?

Comment: set `android:focusable="true"` property to `RelativeLayout`...

Comment: @Gopal Rao: Not helping :(